# Domain of the inverse of a rational function in a scheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral and Noetherian scheme . We consider an open subset $U$ of $X$ and $f\in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Hence we may regard $(U,f)$ as a rational function in $X$. I would like to prove that if $p\in X-U$ (and there is no rational function defined at $p$ that is equivalent to $(U,f)$), there exists an open subset $V$ of $X$ containing $p$ such that we may write the inverse rational function of $(U,f)$ as $(V,g)$ for certain $g\in \Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

The idea behind this is that if a rational function has a pole at a point, then its inverse rational function has a zero, and in particular it is defined at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Morally, the point is that, in dimension at least 2, rational maps can fail to be defined at a point in ways that are more complicated than just "having a pole".

Counterexample: let $X=\mathbf A^2$, let $p=(0,0)$, and let $f=\displaystyle \frac{y}{x}$. Then the inverse rational function is $g=\displaystyle \frac{x}{y}$ but (every representative of) that function is not defined at $p$ either.

A bit more conceptually, you can view a rational function on $X$ as a rational map $f: X \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^1$. If $f$ has a pole at $p$, then $f$ is a regular map in a neighbourhood of $p$, and it maps $p$ to $\infty \in \mathbf P^1$. But not every rational map to $\mathbf P^1$ is regular everywhere --- in fact, if $X$ is a projective variety say, "most" rational maps to $\mathbf P^1$ will fail to be regular at some points.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Is there any condition we could impose on $X$ for the result to hold?

Comment: Dear Howard, for quasiprojective schemes the only situation in which this can hold is if $X$ has dimension 1. For any $X$ of dimension 2 or more, one can adapt my counterexample above to show that what you want is not true.

Comment: Thank you. And what if $p$ is the generic point of an irreducible closed subset of $X$ with codimension $1$? Then I think it should be true because of the way that the valuation induced by $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ work, but I don't know how yo prove it.

Comment: @Howard: yes, in that case it is true. Look in Shafarevich or Hartshorne for the proof that a rational map $X \dashrightarrow Y$ to a projective variety $Y$ is defined outside a codimension 2 subset of $X$. Apply this with $Y=\mathbf P^1$.